# Using container element in form widget

Tags: 8, entities, forms

I want to build a widget for a own field type. In the function formElement() of my widget I want the elements wrapped in a div. For this purpose exists the [container element](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Container.php/class/Container/9.1.x). So I build my form:

```
  public function formElement(FieldItemListInterface $items, $delta, array $element, array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $element['myitem'] = [
      '#type' => 'container',
      '#attributes' => [
          'class' => ['my-item'],
      ],
      '#attached' => [
        'library' => [
          'mymodule/mylibrary',
        ],
      ],
    ];
   $element['myitem']['label'] = [
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Label'),
    '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]->label) ? $items[$delta]->label : NULL,
    '#options' => $options_for_label,
  ];     
  //… more elements

  return $element;
}
```

The rendering of the form looks like I wanted.  But the form entries will not be saved. There are no errors and none of the elements were attached to the entity and persisted in the database.

If I don't use the container element and place my elements direct in $element like this:

```
 $element['label'] = [
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => t('Label'),
  '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]->label) ? $items[$delta]->label : NULL,
  '#options' => $options_for_label,
];
//… more elements
```

then all will be saved.

How can I get my widget-form elements be wrapped within a div for styling?

(A similar question using container element within form widget, here with focus at form state [was asked 3 years ago](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/219155/states-in-formelement-for-a-fieldwidget), but without answer :-( )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From WidgetBase::form:

```
// Most widgets need their internal structure preserved in submitted values.
$elements += ['#tree' => TRUE];
```

When customizing the structure you also need to make sure the values get submitted correctly. For example by adding [WidgetInterface::massageFormValues](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21WidgetInterface.php/function/WidgetInterface%3A%3AmassageFormValues/9.0.x) to your widget.

A much easier way though is to keep the standard structure, which is using property names as form keys, and add the container by #prefix/#suffix:

```
$element['label'] = [
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => t('Label'),
  '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]->label) ? $items[$delta]->label : NULL,
  '#options' => $options_for_label,
  '#prefix' => '<div class="my-item">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
];
```